# Unity - Shadows and lights are flashing and disapperaring when player is moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Helllo. I am using Unity engine and I have trouble.
I have trouble with shadows and lighting and I don't know what is causing it. When player moves, shadows and lights are flashing and disappearing. Look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OiEeG7b26qE

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

By default an object can be illuminated by up to 8 lights only. Try Changing the `Camera.renderingPath` in the inspector to differed lighting to have more than 8 lights in one object.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't solve my problem. I noticed that if I increase far clipping plane to 1*10^8 problem was solved, but Unity crashing when I have large far clipping plane.

Comment: Try to optimize it by reducing draw calls if unity is crashing.